# AppDelegate.swift function returning errors after converting to swift 3 (cannot convert to PFBooleanResultBlock?)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I recently converted my app from the previous version of swift to swift 3.0 (and also got the most recent version of Xcode) and, among many other errors, I received the following one:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let installation = PFInstallation.current()
        installation.setDeviceTokenFrom(deviceToken)
        installation.saveInBackground()

        PFPush.subscribeToChannel(inBackground: "") { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) in
            if succeeded {
                print("ParseStarterProject successfully subscribed to push notifications on the broadcast channel.\n");
            } else {
                print("ParseStarterProject failed to subscribe to push notifications on the broadcast channel with error = %@.\n", error)
            }
        }
    }
```

This came from an SDK that I downloaded as a template (the PF is referring to Parse framework... I am using a Parse-server hosted by Heroku). The error is returned saying: "Cannot convert value of type '(Bool,NSError?)-> ()' to expected argument type 'PFBooleanResultBlock?'"

Not sure how to fix this. Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can change your code like this:

```
    PFPush.subscribeToChannel(inBackground: "", block: {(succeeded, error) -> Void in
        if succeeded {
            print("ParseStarterProject successfully subscribed to push notifications on the broadcast channel.\n");
        } else {
            print("ParseStarterProject failed to subscribe to push notifications on the broadcast channel with error = %@.\n", error)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With **Swift 3** you can write this:

```
  PFPush.subscribeToChannel(inBackground: "") { (succeeded, error) in
        if succeeded {
            print("ParseStarterProject successfully subscribed to push notifications on the broadcast channel.\n")
        } else {
            print("ParseStarterProject failed to subscribe to push notifications on the broadcast channel with error = %@.\n", error)
        }
    }
```