# Parse Starter kit for Swift 3

Tags: swift, facebook, parse-platform, swift3, parse-server

I've downloaded the ParseStarterProject version 1.14.3 and after download it asks me to convert to swift 3. After that gives me an error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(Bool, NSError?) -> ()' to expected argument type 'PFBooleanResultBlock?'
```

Code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let installation = PFInstallation.current()
    installation?.setDeviceTokenFrom(deviceToken)
    installation?.saveInBackground()

    PFPush.subscribeToChannel(inBackground: "") { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) in
        if succeeded {
            print("ParseStarterProject successfully subscribed to push notifications on the broadcast channel.\n")
        } else {
            print("ParseStarterProject failed to subscribe to push notifications on the broadcast channel with error = %@.\n", error)
        }
    } as! PFBooleanResultBlock as! PFBooleanResultBlock as! PFBooleanResultBlock as! PFBooleanResultBlock as! PFBooleanResultBlock as! PFBooleanResultBlock as! PFBooleanResultBlock
}
```

I tried solving with another thread ([AppDelegate.swift function returning errors after converting to swift 3 (cannot convert to PFBooleanResultBlock?)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39646261/appdelegate-swift-function-returning-errors-after-converting-to-swift-3-cannot/39684760#39684760))

But gives me this error:

```
 "Expected ) in the expression list"
```

[http://imgur.com/nkdnEZp](https://imgur.com/nkdnEZp)

Comment: Is the list of 7 `as! PFBooleanResultBlock` a typo? Why are you casting to that type?

Comment: It was Xcode converting automatically to swift 3...But even without that typo it doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like your exact question has already been solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39684760/6658553

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AppDelegate.swift function returning errors after converting to swift 3 (cannot convert to PFBooleanResultBlock?)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39646261/appdelegate-swift-function-returning-errors-after-converting-to-swift-3-cannot)

Comment: I saw that and tried it, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: 2 downvotes when I already said that that thread didn't help? Cmon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce the same bug, I just replace the swift3 generated code with:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let installation = PFInstallation.current()
    installation?.setDeviceTokenFrom(deviceToken)
    installation?.saveInBackground()


    PFPush.subscribeToChannel(inBackground: "") { (succeeded, error) in
        if succeeded {
            print("ParseStarterProject successfully subscribed to push notifications on the broadcast channel.\n")
        } else {
            print("ParseStarterProject failed to subscribe to push notifications on the broadcast channel with error = %@.\n", error)
        }
    }

}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    if error._code == 3010 {
        print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.\n")
    } else {
        print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@\n", error)
    }
}
```

An it works

My project is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw18wEgGhabxaVBqMjF5Rm9wZzg)

Comment: THANK YOU!! Most people just down voted because they don't even check that swift changed again and there is a new problem and you solve it. THANK YOU AGAIN.

Comment: @RenatoPimpão It is true !  No problem, I glad that solve your problem

Comment: Julien, this simple "error._code" just saved my day. I have searched out how to manage the Optional<Error> everywhere to no avail. I had to ignore a code=1 value but dismantling that error object seems so whacky. Why Apple makes some simple things like getting error.code so hard is beyond me.